# Capture a RTSP Stream on an android device

Tags: android, capture, rtsp

I want to capture a RTSP video stream from an ip camera with my Nexus S. To watch the stream with a VideoView and the mediaplayer is no problem.

I tried to save it like this:

```
                URL url = new URL("rtsp://192.168.4.222:554/ipcam.sdp");
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                ucon.connect();
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(VideoFile);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                isRecording = true;
                baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                int current = 0;
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(VideoFile);
                while (((current = bis.read()) != -1) & isRecording) {
                        baf.append((byte) current);
                        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                        baf.clear();
                }                    
                fos.close();
```

I get a MalformedURLException, because android doesn't support rtsp:// urls.

Has somebody an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution???

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html RTSP is not a supported protocol yet

Comment: Yes its mentioned there to create custom URLStreamHandlerFactory and set it in URL using setURLStreamHandlerFactory (URLStreamHandlerFactory factory) method, but the mystery part is how to create RTSP URLStreamHandlerFactory???

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg libraries through JNI/NDK to capture an rtsp stream. It's not very easy, but it does work.